# Kernel Dev In assembly & C

Tags: c, assembly, x86, osdev, bochs

I am trying to create a simple kernel using assembly and C on linux using bochs. The problem that each time I try calling the c code from the assembly code the emulator gives me an error and resets the simulation. when I start in the 16 bit real mode I use this code

```
global _start

[bits 16]

_start:

mov [BOOT_DRIVE] , dl

mov bp , 0x7000
mov sp , bp

mov bx , 0x0000 ;load 5 sectors to 0x0000(ES):0x9000(BX)
mov es , bx
mov bx , KERNEL_OFFSET
mov dh , 15
mov dl , [BOOT_DRIVE]
call disk_load

mov dx , [es:KERNEL_OFFSET]
call print_hex

call switch_to_pm

jmp $
```

and after switching to the protected mode this is the code

```
[bits 32]
extern kmain

begin_pm:

;print a char to vram for testing and it is printed, this means the switch has suceeded
mov ebx , VRAM_ADDRESS
mov al , 'H'
mov [ebx] , al
mov al , 0x07
inc ebx
mov [ebx] , al

call kmain

jmp $
```

and the c function basically does nothing just an empty one

about the commands I am using I use these

```
nasm $asm_file_name.asm -f elf -o $asm_file_name.o
gcc -ffreestanding -c $c_file_name.c -o $c_file_name.o
ld -o $c_file_name.bin -Ttext 0x7c00 $asm_file_name.o $c_file_name.o --oformat binary
dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=$c_file_name.bin of=$floppy_name.img
```

I don't where is the problem. Any ideas ?

Note:
I am using the following GDT and switch_to_pm functions

```
    ;GDT
gdt_start:

    gdt_null:
        dd 0x0
        dd 0x0

    gdt_code: ;the code segment descriptor
        ; base = 0x0 , limit = 0xfffff ,
        ; 1 st flags : ( present )1 ( privilege )00 ( descriptor type )1 -> 1001 b
        ; type flags : ( code )1 ( conforming )0 ( readable )1 ( accessed )0 -> 1010 b
        ; 2 nd flags : ( granularity )1 (32 - bit default )1 (64 - bit seg )0 ( AVL )0 -> 1100 b
        dw 0xffff
        ; Limit (bits 0 -15)
        dw 0x0
        ; Base (bits 0 -15)
        db 0x0
        ; Base ( bits 16 -23)
        db 10011010b ; 1st flags , type flags
        db 11001111b ; 2nd flags , Limit (bits 16 -19)
        db 0x0
        ; Base ( bits 24 -31)

    gdt_data: ; the data segment descriptor
        ; Same as code segment except for the type flags :
        ; type flags : ( code )0 ( expand down )0 ( writable )1 ( accessed )0 -> 0010 b
        dw 0xffff
        ; Limit ( bits 0 -15)
        dw 0x0
        ; Base ( bits 0 -15)
        db 0x0
        ; Base ( bits 16 -23)
        db 10010010b ; 1 st flags , type flags
        db 11001111b ; 2 nd flags , Limit ( bits 16 -19)
        db 0x0
        ; Base ( bits 24 -31)

    gdt_end:
    ; The reason for putting a label at the end of the
    ; GDT is so we can have the assembler calculate
    ; the size of the GDT for the GDT decriptor ( below )
    ; GDT descriptior
    gdt_descriptor:
        dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
        dd gdt_start

    ; Size of our GDT , always less one
    ; of the true size
    ; Start address of our GDT
    ; Define some handy constants for the GDT segment descriptor offsets , which
    ; are what segment registers must contain when in protected mode. For example ,
    ; when we set DS = 0 x10 in PM , the CPU knows that we mean it to use the
    ; segment described at offset 0 x10 ( i.e. 16 bytes ) in our GDT , which in our
    ; case is the DATA segment (0 x0 -> NULL ; 0 x08 -> CODE ; 0 x10 -> DATA )
    CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
    DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
[bits 16]

switch_to_pm:

cli
lgdt[gdt_descriptor]

mov eax , cr0
or eax , 0x1
mov cr0 , eax

jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm

[bits 32]

init_pm:

mov ax , DATA_SEG
mov ds , ax
mov ss , ax
mov es , ax
mov fs , ax
mov gs , ax

mov ebp , 0x9000
mov esp , ebp

jmp begin_pm
```

Comment: Where's your `switch_to_pm`? Did you try to disassemble the resultant binary and see if there any wrong addresses in it? I'm pretty sure there are.

Comment: After disassembling the code I found the call to the c function has the right address.

Comment: Well, did you try adding `jmp $` right after `begin_pm` ? especially `call kmain` may fail if you forgot to setup ss or ds.

Comment: What does the bochs log say about the exception? You may very well get the eip in the log.

Comment: Can we see `switch_to_pm`? because that part is usually pretty hard to get right

Comment: What about `GDT` contents and `GDTR`?

Comment: about setting ss and ds they are both set using mov ax,DATA_SEG , mov ds,ax and mov ss,ax where DATA_SEG in the offset of the data segment in the gdt. About trying jmp $ I tries doing so and it worked fine, it only crashes when I add call kmain !!
about the exception part it says: exception(): 3rd (13) exception with no resolution, shutdown status is 00h, resetting

Comment: I have updated the post :)
both GDT and switch_to_pm are there.

Comment: Well, a simple idea would be to disassemble `kmain` then put the assembly in your .asm file, rename it to kmain2, call kmain2 instead of kmain  and see by putting jmp $ at different places how far does the code go before resetting.

Comment: Well, I did so and it worked fine 
the only problem is when I call it as a c function. Does the linking command has something to do with this ?!

Comment: Is the generated  `$c_file_name.bin` within the 512 size limit?

Comment: no, its 600 bytes !!!
but shouldn't using a floppy image and then loading the rest of the kernel from the disk make such thing not a problem ?

Comment: If you put `jmp $` right before `call kmain`, does it still crash?

Comment: I think you forgot to `jmp 0000:0x9000` !!

Comment: I don't think `0x0000(ES):0x9000(BX)` is right because 0x7c00+0x200(bootsector size)=0x7e00 and not 0x9000.

Comment: It worked !!!
I removed some extra code and it worked !!
thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

`call kmain` will try to find the function at the address as if the whole code was loaded at 0x7c00. However, the code in its entirety is loaded from disk into 0x9000. Thus you need to ask the linker to fix up the address it uses as the address for `kmain`.

Or even better, as @AlexeyFrunze suggests, load the code starting from the second sector into the place in memory directly after where the first sector is loaded by BIOS.

Comment: If the OP simply loads the remaining sectors at 0x7e00(=0x7c00+0x200), it should work, unless there's another mistake.